# Swift: Setting AVAudioSession Output Volume

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to set the AVAudioSession outputVolume?

```
    self.audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    self.audioSession.setActive(true, error: nil)
    self.audioSession.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "outputVolume", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    self.audioSession.outputVolume
```

Currently I am able to access the outputVolume, but I am having troubles of finding a way to set it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `outputVolume` property is read-only. This is due to Apple's conviction that a good user experience will be broken if apps unexpectedly modify sound volume beyond user control.

From the AVAudioSession docs:

> The system wide output volume can be set directly only by the user; to provide volume control in your app, use the MPVolumeView class

So this is your only (easy) option...

```
  MPVolumeView *myVolumeView =
    [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview: myVolumeView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the main volume using the following on iOS 8

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:0.0];
```

for info, the code is called thru a Cordova pluggin. This effects the main volume (the device volume popup show the new volume when code is called)