# Setting the system volume in Swift under IOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio

Ok,

This gets the system volume, works well.

```
var volume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
print("output volume: \(volume)")
```

But how do I set the system volume [in Swift] please

Comment: check: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/volume-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: take a look to this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/28617937/5229157

Answer (score 17):

Here is what you need to do with latest **iOS 10.2**

**Step 1.** Import MediaPlayer

```
import MediaPlayer
```

**Step 2.** Add extension

```
//Update system volume
extension MPVolumeView {
    static func setVolume(_ volume: Float) {
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
            slider?.value = volume
        }
    }
}
```

Step 3. Change volume this way

```
 //Update system volume
 MPVolumeView.setVolume(0.2)
```

Thanks to [trungduc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740234/1371853)

Comment: Why we need dispatch time here? can you please tell me? Thanks! Working Fine!

Comment: Same question. Tell us pls, Why do we need DispatchQ and DispatchTime here? (if you know of course)

Answer (score 10):

First you need to import media player like,

```
import MediaPlayer
```

Then you can set the system volume like,

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
if let view = volumeView.subviews.first as? UISlider
{
     view.value = 0.1   // set b/w 0 t0 1.0       
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It seems to work, but AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume still reports the volume with the same value, so perhaps this is not quite the answer I was looking for?

Comment: How to hide volume hud? I tried view.isHidden = false and volumeView.isHidden, but no luck...

Comment: This works pretty well.  Anyone know how Apple feels about wrt App Review?

Comment: I've seen a lot of apps that do this, and they made it through app review.  That said, I'm sure Apple doesn't like it, or they'd give us a real API.  As far as hiding it, I know in the past, you used to be able to hide it by setting opacity or alpha to 0.01 or something like that.  Haven't tried recently.

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Comment: It does not work tried on XCode 13.2.1 with Swift 5.5, but the upper one works fine