# SWIFTUI change sound level

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

How can I change iOS sound level with SwiftUI

`Slider(value: $viewModel.soundLevel, in: 0...1,step: 0.0625,onEditingChanged: {
                data in self.viewModel.doSomething() })`

and MyClass

`func doSomething(){
        print("\(soundLevel)")
    }`

I got soundLevel but how I set iOS sound level

Answer (score 2):

You can change the Device sound level using the `MediaPlayer`. Setting the Slider of `MPVoulumeView()` will do the job.

Its really easy if you use the extension provided here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57449875/12233264

```
import MediaPlayer

extension MPVolumeView {
    static func setVolume(_ volume: Float) -> Void {
        let volumeView = MPVolumeView()
        let slider = volumeView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01) {
            slider?.value = volume
        }
    }
}
```

Using it in SwiftUI:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var soundLevel: Float = 0.5

    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $soundLevel, in: 0...1,step: 0.0625, onEditingChanged: { data in
            MPVolumeView.setVolume(self.soundLevel)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! But is not perfect because when change slider position not every time I saw in left corner system sound icon :(

Answer (score -3):

It's not best approach but you can try:

Using it in your viewModel class:

```
@Published var soundLevel: Float = 0 {
    didSet{
        MPVolumeView.setVolume(soundLevel)
    }
}
```

Using it in SwiftUI:

```
Slider(value: $viewModel.soundLevel, in: 0...1, step: 0.0625)
```