# iOS, Changing Call Volume

Tags: ios, call, avaudiosession, audiounit, callkit

I am trying to change the call volume programmatically and searched a lot about it. I couldn't find a resource that is implementing it. some of my search links below.

- [Setting the system volume in Swift under IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873962/setting-the-system-volume-in-swift-under-ios)
- [Swift: Setting AVAudioSession Output Volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617635/swift-setting-avaudiosession-output-volume/28617937#28617937)

They do change the Media volume but not ones with related to call that I am trying to manipulate.

I am able to listen to the changes using a NotificationCenter. Code Below:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeChangeListener), name: NSNotification.Name("AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)

@objc func volumeChangeListener(notification: NSNotification) {
print("VOLUME CHANGE: (notification.userInfo?.["AVSystemController_AudioVolumeNotificationParameter"] as? Float)")
}
```

but can't change the volume of call Programmatically. I would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: If you are taking about the inbuilt phone call volume, you can't as it isn't your audio.

Comment: So Paulw, I can't change the call volume any other way?

Answer (score -1):

Discussions here
[How to change device Volume on iOS - not music volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286744/how-to-change-device-volume-on-ios-not-music-volume)

works well with none-Call volume (even on iOS 15.4).

However, changing volume during call, I can see the UI changes:
[image]

But there isn't any call volume change.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31414193)